# Browser compatibility issue with CSS Groove border

Tags: html, css, border

I am having a problem with using a goove border because it looks VERY different in one of the browsers (Firefox) than the rest and not much according to the W3 spec:

> **w3.org**: "Looks as if it were carved in the canvas. (This is typically achieved
>   by creating a “shadow” from two colors that are slightly lighter and
>   darker than the ‘border-color’.)"

The Firefox version is definitly not "slightly" lighter and causes a problem on a dark background.

[image: Groove Border]
Are there are tricks or techniques to get around this and make it look closer to the chrome version in the middle?

Comment: Not really much you can do about it. How browsers choose to interpret the spec is up t them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate the effect using a pseudo element with half the border of the element
And opposite color arrangement

```
.a {
    border: 60px groove #233232;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.b {
    border: solid 60px #233232;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-left-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    top: -220px;
}

.b:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: -30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 30px #233232;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-right-color: red;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wcdo8o81/)

I have choose a red color for the demo, to make it more visible. But of course you can set that to whatever you want

Comment: This is a really good workaround. I simplified it to my needs of only needing the bottom border: http://jsfiddle.net/mLt1yvLw/1/  - It is actually similar(only if not doing all four sides) to my primitive idea of just adding a spare set of div tags around the box and adding another color of bottom-border to that div. - Anyway, I will have to weight the options of mass modifying the already complex site for something insignificant as this or just pick another color that will work better in both browsers.  -- Thanks for your help.